# Delete multiple records from Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, console

I'm trying to delete multiple records in my database from the Rails console. I know i can do User.find(1).destroy. What if I want to delete all users with ids 100 - 200. Is there a way to do this in the console?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do something like `User.delete_all("id > 100 AND id < 200")`.

Comment: Or: `User.where("id > 100 AND id < 200").delete_all`

Comment: Be aware that `delete_all` and `delete` will not run callbacks, whereas `destroy_all` and `destroy` will run them. In most cases, you will want to use `destroy_all` and not skip the callbacks.

Comment: @Mischa Altough similat I find this more accurate, the query will run only on the selected subset.

Comment: @PatrickOscity Sorry, I'm new to rails. I just ran a delete_all and it gave me back the number of rows deleted. What do you mean by callbacks? Why should destroy_all be used instead? Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderD delete_all will just remove the records from the database, whereas destroy_all will invoke callbacks before actually deleting the records. Callbacks allow you to implement features like soft delete (e.g. via paranoid gem) or for example prevent deletion of records in certain cases. Delete_all will just ignore this.

Comment: @AlexanderD what do you mean "more accurate" and "the query will run only on the selected subset"? Both ways do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @PatrickOscity Oh, so with callbacks more actions are available before the actual delete.

Comment: @Mischa I know, but I personally prefer to take a subset of elements and then delete them, rather than deleting a subset of elements from all the records

Answer (score 4):

New syntax in Rails 5 is the syntax Mischa mentions in his comment: `User.where("id > 100 AND id < 200").delete_all`

Passing conditions to `delete_all` will be deprecated in rails 5.1.